# Dropzone is not working with any browser

Tags: jsp, dropzone

I have one project which is already done by someone else. And i have to do minute changes. The project contains dropzone.js. Am sorry if it's silly to ask this question but i don't have any idea of how dropzone will work. Problem is if am running complete project just for testing purpose it is working fine in other PC. But if am trying it in netbeans browser is not displaying dropzone itself. I tried to run with mozzilla, chrome and IE but its not working with anything. Can anyone help me to understand why am not able get dropzone. Do i have to change any setting in netbean or browser? Kindly help.

```
<script src="js/dropzone.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/dropzone.css">


<form name="form1" id="my-awesome-dropzone" action="UploadServlet" class="dropzone"></form>
```

Comment: http://jsbin.com/temizemufu/edit?html,output — I can't reproduce the problem. The most likely explanation is that you got one or both of your URLs wrong.

Comment: Mozilla is a company that makes a number of different products. Their name only has one "z" in it. The browser is called Firefox. You don’t call Chrome “Google", Edge “Microsoft” or Safari “Apple”, do you?

Comment: Sorry my mistake i mean Firefox. If there was a problem with URL it'll not work on other PC right? In my case same project i run on other PC and it worked fine but in my PC it's not working.